# Acceso a atributos de una estructura por medio de referencias en C++

Tags: c++, poo, manejo-de-memoria

Tengo una estructura nodo que tiene la siguiente forma

```
   struct Node {
      bool word;
      int frecuencia;
      char c;
      Node* arr [ALPHABET];
    };
```

El problema es que cuando imprime la palabra muestra una serie de caracteres basura y luego típico Segmentation fault, agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Ok gracias por la ayuda, para ponerte en contexto estoy usando una estructura de datos trie, el programa recibe un string (prefijo), va a una función buscar que asigna el nodo donde esta el ultimo carácter del string, ese nodo se lo paso a la función auto completar que lo que hace o debería de hacer es encontrar todos los sufijos del string ingresados.

El parametro que le paso a autocomplete en su primera llamada viene desde la funcion search.

```
  Node* act;
  search(&word[0], act);
  list<string> leftOver = autocomplete(act);
```

Aquí esta la función buscar

```
bool search (char* word, Node* actual) {
  Node* cursor = root;
  int index;
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++) {
    //hallar el indice del caracter en el alfabeto
    for (int j = 0; j < ALPHABET; j++) {
      if (tolower(word[i]) == chars[j]) {
        index = j;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (cursor->arr[index] == NULL) {
      actual = cursor;
      return false;
    }else {
      cursor = cursor->arr[index];
    }
  }

   actual = cursor;
   if (cursor->word) {
    cursor->frecuencia += 1;
    return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Esta es la función auto completar

```
list<string> autocomplete (Node* cursor) {
  list <string> words;
  Node* children [ALPHABET];

  if (cursor->arr != NULL) {
      memcpy(children, cursor->arr, sizeof(Node*[ALPHABET]));
  }else {return words;}

  for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET; i++) {
    Node* child = children[i];
    if (child != NULL) {
      string word = "";
      word += child->c;
      if (child->word) {
          words.push_back(word);
      }

      list <string> leftOver = autocomplete(child);

      // cout << leftOver.size() << endl;
      if (leftOver.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < leftOver.size(); i++) {
          words.push_back(word + leftOver.back());
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return words;
}
```

Comment: Muestra más código. Si **llega** a escribir la palabra, el problema está **despues** del código que muestras. Si no llega a escribirla, el problema esta **antes**. Ese código que muestras es correcto.

Comment: Inicializa la memoria de tu puntero

Comment: Podría dar SEGFAULT si el puntero fuera == NULL, pero entonces el error estaría **antes** de mostrar la cadena, y, por los datos de la pregunta, no está claro cuando se produce el error.

Answer (score 2):

Estás escribiendo código C++, luego la definición de `Node`:

```
typedef struct Node {
  bool word;
  int frecuencia;
  char c;
  struct Node* arr [ALPHABET];
} Node;
```

Debería quedar así:

```
struct Node {
  bool word;
  int frecuencia;
  char c;
  Node* arr [ALPHABET];
};
```

Nota que C y C++ son lenguajes diferentes y cada uno tiene sus propias características... de hecho no todo lo que puedas hacer en C será válido en C++ y viceversa. Lo lógico al programar en C++ es que hagas uso de la sintaxis propia de C++ aunque sea únicamente por claridad y coherencia con el resto del código que te vas a encontrar.

Por lo que comentas, la única posiblidad de que se produzca el error (salvo que haya algo que no hayas contado) es que tengas un código como el siguiente:

```
Node* cursor;
string word; // = ""; <--- La parte comentada sobra
word += cursor->c;
cout << word << endl;
```

Y la razón de este problema es que `cursor` es un puntero que no hace referencia a una posición de memoria válida.

Las soluciones específicas a este problema son dependientes de que aportes más información. Sin embargo intentaré hacer algunas asunciones.

Puedes optar por usar la variable por valor:

```
Node cursor;
cursor.c = 'A';
string word;
word += cursor.c;
cout << word << endl;
```

Incluso si este código está embebido en una función podrías tener algo tal que:

```
void func(Node& cursor) // <--- Una referencia
{
  string word;
  word += cursor.c;
  cout << word << endl;
}

Node* miCursor = /* inicialización */
func(*miCursor);
```

La ventaja de usar referencias es que impides que alguien pueda llamar a la función con un puntero nulo. Básicamente desplazas el error a la llamada a la función, lo que simplifica la depuración de los errores:

```
Node* miCursor = nullptr; // nullptr es de C++11 y es más seguro que usar NULL o 0
func(*miCursor); // ERROR
```

Y por supuesto no da problema si utilizas objetos por valor:

```
Node miCursor;
func(miCursor); // OK
```

Eso sí, al final todo se reduce a saber qué almacena cada variable, y en este caso tienes que asegurarte que `cursor` está apuntando a un objeto válido so pena de leer posiciones de memoria erróneas.

Comment: Es lo que pasa cuando no aportan todos los datos, que hay que soltar unas parrafadas que no veas y ser adivinos.. Fijate que en la pregunta, llama 'referencia' a un puntero, así que estara pensando que eso es lo que el hace, pasarlo por referencia ... xD

Comment: Lo se, pero también piensa que a veces se hace sin mala intención. Si alguien está aprendiendo es normal que a veces no sepa cómo expresar correctamente el problema que tiene. Si tu intuición te dice que deberías responder, yo te animo a que lo hagas, aunque la pregunta no sea del todo correcta y luego toque editar las respuestas.

Comment: Es que esta en concreto se podría englobar como 'referida a punteros', y ya llevo varias con respuestas casi iguales (varian los contextos, pero la idea central es la misma, que no se aclaran con los punteros y los array). Habria que ponerlas con sección propia en alguna parte. Y encima, algunos no dan ni las gracias; ni un mal punto.

Comment: El problema de estas confusiones se suele producir cuando la gente pasa de C a C++ e intenta hacer programas siguiendo la misma filosofía... craso error ya que lenguajes diferentes = soluciones diferentes.